# Unable to select values from the list after giving inputValue prop in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

my goal is to programmatically manage focus and blur and change style of select container correspondingly when user interacts with my form. Here is what I have done

```
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  
  const handleFocus = (e) => {
    // console.log(e.target.id);
    setIsBlurred({ ...isBlurred, [e.target.id]: false });
  };

  const handleBlur = (e) => {
    // handle blur
    e.target.value.length === 0 &&
      setIsBlurred({ ...isBlurred, [e.target.id]: true });
  };
 
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    // console.log(e);
    handleFormData({ ...formData, [e.id]: e.value });
    setInputValue(e.value);
  };

  const style = {
    control: (base, inputValue) => ({
      ...base,
      borderColor: helpText && inputValue.length === 0 ? "red" : "e4e4e4",
    }),
  };

// rest of code //
<Select 
  options={options}
  onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
  inputValue={inputValue}
  handleBlur={(e) => handleBlur(e)}
  handleFocus={(e) => handleFocus(e)}
  styles={style}
  inputId="sensor_type"
  helpText={/* a boolean value based on whether field is blurred or not*/} 
/>
```

So there are two difficulties

1. When i'm giving the inputValue prop to the react select, after selecting the first element, I'm no longer able to open the dropdown like so (image attached below)
2. When I'm not giving inputValue, i'm unable to access the select components value via e.target.value in handleBlur function which takes care of my form validation.

so how do I solve this problem I'm not able to select any other value after my initial selection what should I do, any help would be appreciated. [image]
[image]

Comment: I think if you are using onChange event you need to update the value prop of react select as well since react component will treat it as a controlled component. Do that and try removing the inputValue prop completely.

Comment: Also what do you mean by unable to access the value in the blur callback?

Comment: What I mean is that , after selecting an option e.target.value is showing an empty string, e.target.value is showing after I provide inputValue prop but otherwise it isn't showing the value

Comment: Did you try the change in my comment?

Comment: yeah, i was able to solve the issue, I removed inputValue prop, i figured that I need to make it a controlled  component